# want to convert date in US format through java

Tags: java, date

I have the below program in which dates need to be transformed in US format dates as you can see are being entered by me but
still they need to be transformed in US format which is not happening rite now

please advise how to achieve this below is my code

```
 public class DateFormattingTest {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy");


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println ("03/20/2020-->:" + extractDate("03/20/2020") );
         System.out.println ("2033-05-01-->:" + extractDate("2033-05-01") );
        System.out.println ("08-05-34-->:" + extractDate("08-05-34") );
         System.out.println ("30-DEC-2013 -->:" + extractDate("30-DEC-2013") );
         System.out.println ("DEC-31-2013 -->:" + extractDate("DEC-31-2013") );


    }

    public static Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

        String [] datePatternsUS = {"d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy","dd-MM-yy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yy","dd-MMM-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy",
                "dd/MM/yy","dd/MMM/yy","dd/MMM/yyyy"};

        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatternsUS);
        }
        catch (Exception except) {
                except.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }


}
```

upon execution i get the below output.. which is not correct please advise how to correct it in US format

```
03/20/2020-->:Tue Aug 03 00:00:00 IST 2021
2033-05-01-->:Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 IST 2006
08-05-34-->:Mon May 08 00:00:00 IST 2034
30-DEC-2013 -->:Mon Dec 30 00:00:00 IST 2013
DEC-31-2013 -->:null
java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: DEC-31-2013
```

Comment: None of the formats in your program are US format. A US format would have the month `M` before the day `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formatter and return `String` from `extractDate` (and re-arrange the date formats in your array):

```
    private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println ("03/20/2020-->:" + extractDate("03/20/2020") );
         System.out.println ("2033-05-01-->:" + extractDate("2033-05-01") );
         System.out.println ("08-05-34-->:" + extractDate("08-05-34") );
         System.out.println ("30-DEC-2013 -->:" + extractDate("30-DEC-2013") );
         System.out.println ("DEC-31-2013 -->:" + extractDate("DEC-31-2013") );
    }

    public static String extractDate(String dateStr) {
        String [] datePatternsUS = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy","MMM-dd-yyyy" };

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatternsUS);
            return outputDate.format(date);
        }
        catch (Exception except) {
                except.printStackTrace();
        }        
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is, however, that `"yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yy"` are conflicting patterns, so that (depending on order) either line 2 or 3 outputs a bogus date.

Output is:

> 03/20/2020-->:03/08/2021
>
> 2033-05-01-->:23/11/2006
>
> 08-05-34-->:08/05/2034
>
> 30-DEC-2013 -->:30/12/2013
>
> DEC-31-2013 -->:31/12/2013

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add the pattern `MMM-dd-yyyy` to your patterns. I've symplified your method `extractDate()` and I've added `Locale.US`. Now it returns all your input dates correctly.

```
static String [] formatStrings  = {"d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy",
        "dd-MM-yy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yy","dd-MMM-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy",
        "dd/MM/yy","dd/MMM/yy","dd/MMM/yyyy",
        "MMM-dd-yyyy"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println ("03/20/2020-->:" + extractDate("03/20/2020") );
    System.out.println ("2033-05-01-->:" + extractDate("2033-05-01") );
    System.out.println ("08-05-34-->:" + extractDate("08-05-34") );
    System.out.println ("30-DEC-2013 -->:" + extractDate("30-DEC-2013") );
    System.out.println ("DEC-31-2013 -->:" + extractDate("DEC-31-2013") );

}


public static Date extractDate(String dateString) {

    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString, Locale.US).parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If i run your code, the first two outputs are: 03/20/ **2020**-->:Tue Aug 03 00:00:00 CEST **2021**, **2033**-05-01-->:Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 CET **2006**. I don't think this is, what OP wanted. I think he wants all dates formatted with this pattern: dd/MM/yyyy. I might be wrong, but the `ParseException` caused by the original code is just a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have any pattern matching the last format of date. Add this to your array.

```
MMM-dd-yyyy
```